# Disable bootstrap collapse hide function when content is visible/expanded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have really simple question. A want to use **Bootstrap 3 collapse** function for showing up some content **BUT** i want to disable `hide` function.

So, when i click on some link or button, some content appears, but when content is once `visible` and i click on the link one more time, content should retain visible (so i can highlight content instead of hiding on link clicks  see example).

My specific usecase:

```
<button class="reply-link note date" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="reply-form" data-target="#reply-form">reply</button>
<div id="reply-form" class="collapse media">
     reply form html code ...
</div>
```

I want to show up `reply form` by `reply button`. Next reply button click will not hide the reply form but add focus on some reply form element.

Is there some common way how to do this by using **Bootstrap 3**?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyone  to show up the code too rather than just a problem..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `shown` event of the collapse to disable (or hide, remove, etc..) the trigger button..

```
$('#collapseExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/DWOCEWVPxE

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove `data-toggle="collapse"` from your HTML.
2. Show your collapse div on click (using JS).

HTML:

```
<button class="reply-link note date" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="reply-form" data-target="#reply-form">reply</button>
<div id="reply-form" class="collapse media">
     reply form html code ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".reply-link").click(function () {
  $('.media').collapse('show');
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/vXGAOV)

Comment: Thanks, this is what i want.